# javascript style.display block two toggles together

Tags: javascript, css, display

Simple question: why does javascript allow you the first block of code, but not the second??? I'm just trying to hide one div as I show another. The simple toggle works (first block of code) the second one blows up and javascript gives "an undefined function"  (showtablediv) in the console.

```
function showtablediv(){

    var xfor = document.getElementById('foreachhold');
    var xtable = document.getElementById('tableviewhold');

    if(xfor.style.display == 'block')
        xfor.style.display = 'none';
    else
      xfor.style.display = 'block';
}
function showtablediv(){

    var xfor = document.getElementById('foreachhold');
    var xtable = document.getElementById('tableviewhold');

    if(xfor.style.display == 'block')
        xfor.style.display = 'none';
        xtable.style.display ='block';       
else
      xfor.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: hey, stackflow's software truncated the code block on the bottom. the problem is attempting to do two style.display in the same function: "table.style.display = 'block';

Comment: Are you getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` exception by any chance?

Comment: You are missings brackets around your `if` and `else` statements. See [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) to learn how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing more than one line of code after `if(xfor.style.display == 'block')`. if you don't use brackets then the limit of lines of code is one

```
function showtablediv(){

    var xfor = document.getElementById('foreachhold');
    var xtable = document.getElementById('tableviewhold');

    if(xfor.style.display == 'block')
        xfor.style.display = 'none';
    else
      xfor.style.display = 'block';
}
function showtablediv(){

    var xfor = document.getElementById('foreachhold');
    var xtable = document.getElementById('tableviewhold');

    if(xfor.style.display == 'block')
        xfor.style.display = 'none';
        xtable.style.display ='block';// the problem is this line       
    else
      xfor.style.display = 'block';
}
```